# Generate PDF from html in jQuery mobile application

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am new to jQuery mobile and i am working to generate PDF from dynamic HTML through the mobile app, I have already used couple of plugins like **HTML2PDF**, here I am getting iText issue in HTML2PDF.
Please help me or guide me for the another plugin that support jQuery Mobile.

Comment: could you please specify what kind of issues? could you please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply

Code :- 

 var docDefinition = {content:[
                           'First paragraph',

                           'Another paragraph'
                 ]};
     try{
       pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download("test_doc.PDF",function (URL) {
      alert("Success PDF : "+URL);
     });
    }catch(e){
         alert("error : "+e);
    }
    
I am using the above code to create and download the PDF, Success PDF is coming successfully but PDF i am not getting

Comment: The above mentioned code, Belongs to pdfMake plugin, Here is the link that I have used :- **https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake**

Comment: While I am trying to use another Cordova plugin HTML2PDF to generate PDF, I am getting **java: package com.itextpdf.text does not exist**,I am using a cordova plugin :- **cordova plugin add https://github.com/makersu/makersu-cordova-plugin-html2pdf.git** and following the mentioned link :- **https://github.com/makersu/makersu-cordova-plugin-html2pdf**